# How to access embedded resources inside a merged DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I have managed to merge DLL files as embedded resource to one DLL, using AssemblyResolve event, but when I try to use that Dll at another console application, I do not have access inside the embedded resources this merged Dll has. For example, this merged Dll contains another Dll of a class library I need to use, and I want to access public methods/interfaces etc.. that this class library has, but it seems I cannot access them from this merged Dll. How can this issue be resolved ?

```
static Dictionary<string, Assembly> dic = null;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var filesList = Directory.EnumerateFiles( //path to Resources folder inside console application, which holds all DLLs that are set as embedded resources );

      foreach (var file in filesList)
      {
           var fname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
           var embRes = "ConsoleAppTest.Resources." + fname + ".dll";
           Console.WriteLine(embRes);
           Load(embRes, fname + ".dll");
       }
       AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
       Console.ReadKey();
 }

static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
     return GetAssembly(args.Name);
}

static void Load(string embeddedResource, string fileName)
 {
            if (dic == null)
                dic = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();

            byte[] assemblyData = null;
            Assembly asm = null;
            Assembly curAsm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            using (Stream stream = curAsm.GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedResource))
            {
                // Either the file is not existed or it is not mark as embedded resource
                if (stream == null)
                    throw new Exception(embeddedResource + " is not found in Embedded Resources.");

                // Get byte[] from the file from embedded resource
                assemblyData = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                try
                {
                    asm = Assembly.Load(assemblyData);

                    // Add the assembly/dll into dictionary
                    dic.Add(asm.FullName, asm);
                    Console.WriteLine(asm.FullName);
                    return;
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Purposely do nothing
                    // Unmanaged dll or assembly cannot be loaded directly from byte[]
                    // Let the process fall through for next part
                }
            }

            bool fileOk = false;
            string tempFile = "";

            //load unmanaged assemblies
            using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                string fileHash = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(assemblyData)).Replace("-", string.Empty); ;

                tempFile = Path.GetTempPath() + fileName;

                if (File.Exists(tempFile))
                {
                    byte[] bb = File.ReadAllBytes(tempFile);
                    string fileHash2 = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(bb)).Replace("-", string.Empty);

                    if (fileHash == fileHash2)
                    {
                        fileOk = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fileOk = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    fileOk = false;
                }
            }

            if (!fileOk)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, assemblyData);
            }

            asm = Assembly.LoadFile(tempFile);

            dic.Add(asm.FullName, asm);
            Console.WriteLine(asm.FullName);
}

static Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyFullName)
{
    if (dic == null || dic.Count == 0)
         return null;

    if (dic.ContainsKey(assemblyFullName))
         return dic[assemblyFullName];

            return null;
}
```

This console application is in .NET Framework 4.5.1 and when I build the solution, it produces an .exe file. Then I change the output type of the project to class library, to get a Dll instead of exe and build it again.  After I get this merged Dll, ConsoleAppTest.dll, I add a reference to it at another test project, but I cannot access the dll that ConsoleAppTest has inside. For example, if it has ClientLibrary.dll inside, I want to access public methods/interfaces  of this ClientLibrary.dll

```
using ConsoleAppTest;

//code to access public methods/interfaces of a dll that is inside ConsoleAppTest.dll included in using statement above
```

Comment: The odds that the name of the embedded resource ends with ".dll" are not good.  Remove all doubt, run ildasm.exe and look at the manifest for the .mresource names.

Comment: I have put Dll files to Resources folder inside project, so yes, there are dll files which I have configured as Embedded Resources.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but VS won't show you the classes and method from references resolved via this method done in runtime